# APIPlatform JWT authentication_token route issue

Tags: php, reactjs, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I use Symfony 5 and React, with docker.

Both containers are on different `docker-compose but` on the same network, so they can see and ping each other.

I installed the bundle with :
 `docker-compose exec php composer require jwt-auth`

Then generated public and private keys with

```
docker-compose exec php sh -c '
    set -e
    apk add openssl
    mkdir -p config/jwt
    jwt_passphrase=${JWT_PASSPHRASE:-$(grep ''^JWT_PASSPHRASE='' .env | cut -f 2 -d ''='')}
    echo "$jwt_passphrase" | openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -pass stdin -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
    echo "$jwt_passphrase" | openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -passin stdin -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
    setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX config/jwt
    setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX config/jwt
'
```

So I got `routes.yaml` file with:

```
authentication_token:
    path: /authentication_token
    methods: ['POST']
```

And `security.yaml` with :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Users
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Now if I try to hit this route with my react front, I got the following errors in my web browser

in `console`

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://localhost:8443/authentication_token", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: trueheaders: Headers {}ok: falseredirected: falsestatus: 404statusText: ""type: "cors"url: "https://localhost:8443/authentication_token"__proto__: Response
```

In `network response`

`Unable to find the controller for path \"\/authentication_token\". The route is wrongly configured`

And if I try to access the route in the browser with :

`https://localhost:8443/authentication_token`

I get :

`No route found for "GET /authentication_token": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)`

I don't understrand why, because I've followed api platform doc:
`https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/`

I send my request through a POST on react :

```
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8443/authentication_token', {
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            })

            console.warn(response)
            const responseData = await response.json()
            console.warn(responseData)
            onConnect(responseData)
```

And I've checked `header request` and `response request`, both are set to the POST method.

Someone has an idea on what I've missed ?

Comment: Have you cleared cache? If you execute `console debug:router`, is the route there?

Comment: Yes cleaned cache multiple time and the route is there when I run debug:router

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but just for reference:
<s>The API Platform documentation example seems to be wrong about this part. Just remove</s>

```
anonymous: true
```

from your respective firewall in security.yaml

Solved the issue for me.

Edit: That was nonsense. However, in my case I just had to make sure that the **Content-Type** Header was correctly set to **application/json**.

Comment: Content-Type was the key for me.